# Unable to update image in MySql DB using PHP prepared statement?

Tags: php

I am trying to Update profile picture stored in a table with Data type as BLOB in MySql database.

It just does not upload anything when i check my table it shows Data length as zero bytes in BLOB column ? I am using prepared statement is there anything i am missing below ?

The worst part is the php file also does not throw any error so i am confused what's wrong ?

html

```
<form action="php/updateProfilePicture.php" method="post" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="file">Profile Picture:</label>
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

php

```
  <?php  
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root123", "xyz", "3306");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "xyz");

  $email = 'xyz@gmail.com';

  $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE  profileinformation SET Image = ? Where email = ? ');
  $null = null;
  $stmt->bind_param($null, $email);
  $stmt->send_long_data(0, file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
  $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errno) {
        echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else
        echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";
    $stmt->close();
    ?>
```

profileinformation table in MySql

```
CREATE TABLE `profileinformation` (
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Industry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Website` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Image` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`)
)
```

Comment: In the bind_param,that 'b' isn't suppose to be there. And what is the use of $null there?

Comment: the 'b' was a mistake i just updated the code, I am using $null because if you look at the function send_long_data i am binding the image in the next line in place of the $null. I also added the Mysql table defination in the above code in case it makes it easy to understand

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Ensure that your connections and prepare query are valid. Output the query and run it manually.

Comment: You never bothered checking if the upload actually succeeded. There's an `['error']` parameter in the $_FILES array for a reason - use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to know if there is an error in the prepared statement do this:

```
if( $stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE  profileinformation SET Image = ? Where email = ? ');){
echo "statement is good";
}
else{
echo 'statement is bad';
```

i think that there is an error binding the parameters it should be like this:

```
    //s is for binding strings
   //i is for binding integers
  // b is for blob
            $stmt->bind_param('bs',$null, $email);
```

If you want to know more about stored procedures click on this link [stored procedures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php)

this link posted above provides this example:

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null);
$fp = fopen("messages.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(0, fread($fp, 8192));
}
fclose($fp);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

it also looks like you did not set the transfer rate parameter

Comment: Thanks a ton ... i did a check my statement was good but i was missing the 'bs' parameter  $stmt->bind_param('bs',$null, $email);

Comment: it uploads file with smaller size however i tried uploading the one in mb it fails  Warning: Error while sending STMT_EXECUTE packet. PID=6016. can you suggest why does it do that ?

Comment: You need to raise max_allowed_packet in your settings or you need to send the blob in smaller packets. this link explains to you how to do it http://oswaldatwork.thetaoofamp.com/2009/11/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing/

Comment: max_allowed_packet is a mysql setting it's not a php.ni setting so you need to find the configuration file for mysql and change it.If you are using a local server it is not hard to do.